# jQuery accordion its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to use the jquery ui accordion plugin and I don't know why its not working.

I came to http://jqueryui.com/ and read the documentation, I choose a theme and then I selected "UI Core toggle all", and then in widgets I selected only "Accordion".

I save the files in my "acc" folder and then I import the files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../acc/css/jquery-ui-style.css" />
<title>Projet</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../acc/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../acc/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../acc/js/acc.js"></script>
```

And then in my **acc.js file** Im starting accordion:

```
$(function (){
    $('.accordion').accordion();
});
```

But its not working, I'm having only my normal html without the accordion.

**My html** is this:

```
 <div class="accordion">

        <h3>Title 1</h3>    
        <div>
            <p>My first post.</p>
        </div>        

        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <div>
            <p>My second post.</p>  
        </div>        

        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <div>
            <p>My third post</p>    
        </div>

    </div><!-- /accordion -->
```

Comment: Where are you placing this HTML file?

Comment: verify your source html page and note if your scripts have been imported correctly

Comment: This html file is in example.php file, in the same file where I have the jQuery imports!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have posted it should work so I can only assume it isn't including your scripts properly

If the acc folder is in the root folder of your website you should consider changing your scripts and css to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acc/css/jquery-ui-style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acc/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acc/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acc/js/acc.js"></script>
```

Remove the dots - as that means you are trying to get to a folder one up from where you are (in the url, not the file with the html).

If this doesn't work then press f12 and check your console, you may have other js errors stopping the the accordion working

Comment: Thank you, the problem was really that! But its trange because I have a  project folder an then I have a tpl folder and acc folder, my example with the html of accordeon is inside the tpl folder, and the jquery scripts are in acc folder that is outside tpl folder! So I guess that I needed to do ../ to came 1 folder back! But it works like you said, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Im not entirely familiar with jQuery UI accordions, but have you tried placing your $('.accordion').accordion(); inside jQuery document.ready ?

See the code below, most likely your accordion is being initialized before the actual html on the page exists. That's assuming you setup your html correctly,and you are including the proper jQuery JavaScript files etc.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('.accordion').accordion();
});
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: `$(function ()` is another way to say ready, believe it helps with library conflicts

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you unchecked the JqueryUI Core, download the standard version of JqueryUI and overwrite the version created.

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5EV4/) shows that the code is correct. If you are missing the core then no widgets will work

```
$(function (){
    $('.accordion').accordion();
});
```