# jQuery Accordion not getting displayed

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a FAQ page that has a jQuery Accordion and a repeater control inside the accordion that will display various questions and answers. The FAQ page has a master page called LaunchPage.Master.

Below is my LaunchPage.Master Code

```html
<html>

<head runat="server">
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport' />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" charset="utf-8" />
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.4 -->
  <link href="content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="content/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link href="content/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="Content/js/jQuery/jQuery_1_7_2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="skin-blue-light sidebar-mini">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="main-header">
      <!-- Logo -->
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
        <span class="logo-mini"> </span>
        <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
      </a>
      <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
        <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button" title="Toggle Full Frame"></a>
        <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
        <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="hidden-xs">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lftSideLabel" runat="server" CssClass="info" />
                                        </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="SettingsIcon" title="Settings" runat="server">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" title="Settings"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="header">Settings</li>
                <li>
                  <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                  <ul class="menu">
                    <li id="nUser" runat="server">
                      <a href="Register.aspx" id="RegisterOption">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-plus text-aqua"></i>Create New User
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="cPassword" runat="server">
                      <a href="changepassword.aspx" id="ChangePasswordOption">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil text-red"></i>Change Password
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                  <a href="LogoutPage.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" title="Logout" ID="Signout">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" title="Logout"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
    <aside class="main-sidebar">
      <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <section class="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
        <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        </ul>
      </section>
      <!-- /.sidebar -->
    </aside>
    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <!-- Main content -->
      <section class="content">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
          </asp:ScriptManager>
          <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
    <footer class="main-footer">
  </div>
  <!-- ./wrapper -->
</body>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
  //Auto redirect to login page
  function SessionExpireAlert(a) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location = "Login.aspx"
    }, a)
  };
</script>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
  $("[id*=Signout]").live("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "Landing.aspx/LogoutIcon",
      data: "{}",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(a) {},
      error: function(a) {
        alert("Error")
      }
    })
  });
</script>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide();
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id", "current");
    $("#content #tab1").fadeIn();
    $("#tabs a").click(function(a) {
      a.preventDefault();
      "current" != $(this).closest("li").attr("id") && ($("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(), $("#tabs li").attr("id", ""), $(this).parent().attr("id", "current"), $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).fadeIn())
    })
  });
</script>
<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script defer="defer" src="Content/js/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->
<script defer="defer" src="Content/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script defer="defer" src="Content/js/AdminApp/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

This is my FAQ.aspx Code

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/LaunchPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FAQ.aspx.cs" Inherits="FAQ" %>

  <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dvAccordian").accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content",
            alwaysOpen: false
          });
        });
      </script>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <section class="content-header">
            </section>
            <div id="dvAccordian" style="width: 99%" runat="server">
              <asp:Repeater ID="rptFAQ" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <div class="s_panel" style="font-family: 'Roboto'; font-size: small">
                    <h1>
                                        <a href="#" class="lblFontSmall" data-content="Tool tip"><%# Eval("Question") %></a>
                                    </h1>
                    <div>
                      <p>
                        <small><span class="lblFontSmall"><%# Eval("Answer") %></span></small>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>
            </div>

            <br />
            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

When I view the FAQ Page, I am not getting the accordions. Rather I am getting only the text. The jQueryUI.js and .CSS links are working fine. I tried to change my script and css link reference to my master page under the head as well as in my FAQ page too. However i am getting the same output as text instead of accordions.

I tried to troubleshoot based on the response provided in these links, however nothing worked.

[jQuery Accordion not working](http://forums.asp.net/t/2029072.aspx?Jquery%20Accordion%20not%20working)

[jQuery accordion its not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271541/jquery-accordion-its-not-working)

[jQuery accordion() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776225/jquery-accordion-not-working)

I am not able to find the root cause of the issue. When I inspect the code, the jQuery is not getting detected and loaded to the dvAccordion control. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I see there has been a downvote for this post. I dont know why that user has downvoted my content. Can the person who downvoted tell me the reason regarding the same? A post can be downvoted if the person who posted it has not tried anything from his side. Or its not clear. I have tried all the workarounds and i cant put all the ones i tried to this post, As it will not give the clear picture of what my issue is. So only i stated in general like "I tried to change my script and css link reference to my master page under the head as well as in my FAQ page too." Moreover mine is a live project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this code as a replacement for jquery accordion.

```js
<!-- JS -->
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  }); < /script>
```

```css
<style> .accordion-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.accordion-content {
  display: none;
}
.accordion-content.default {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content default">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```